# Google Maps Persists on Back Navigation Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps

When using the latest version of Flutter, and navigating from Screen A to Screen B and then back to Screen A, the Google Maps component persists on screen for an extra second.

I was testing this on version 3.10.4 and can confirm this is not an issue on version 3.3.10.

My Flutter Doctor checks out. Not sure what the issue is...

Adding a screen grab and example code below, thanks for the help!

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:test/SecondPage.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.of(context)
              .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage()));
        },
        child: Container(
          height: 60,
          width: 200,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
          child: const Center(child: Text("Go To SecondPage")),
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  Completer<GoogleMapController> controller = Completer();

  SecondPage({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.brown,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text(
          "APPLE",
          style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'FranklinGothicDemiRegular',
              color: Colors.white,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              fontSize: 18),
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 200,
          child: GoogleMap(
            mapToolbarEnabled: false,
            zoomControlsEnabled: false,
            myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
            myLocationEnabled: true,
            gestureRecognizers: <Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>>{
              Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>(
                () => EagerGestureRecognizer(),
              ),
            },
            initialCameraPosition: const CameraPosition(
              target: LatLng(0, 0),
              zoom: 15.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you think this is a bug in flutter / library due to a recent update, it would be better for you to post this as an issue in the `google_maps_flutter` library here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3A%22p%3A+maps%22

Comment: Hmm. Not sure about this and I don't feel like digging into it, but any time you have an `//ignore` you're breaking things. Don't do that. If you have to make your widget into a StatefulWidget do that instead. A mutable StatelessWidget is going to break things. But my feeling is that this is to do with the GoogleMap widget which does change over time. If you want to make sure it is hidden you could use a Visibility or Opacity class.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your widget with Visibility widget and make

the visible property to false before you make navigator.pop(context)

like this :

```html
              bool visible = true;
              
              
              InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    visible = false;
                    setState(() {});
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },),
                   Visibility(
              visible: visible,
              child: GoogleMap(
                onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
                initialCameraPosition: position,
                mapType: MapType.normal,
            ),)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).